# Laravel Form Helpers in blade(Generate input tag with old input)

Tags: php, laravel

what is `Input::old` in laravel

I have seen a tutorial where they have created input elements like

```
{{ Form::email('emailId', Input::old('emailId'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Input::old` is to keep the `Input` values upon the next request.**

From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input):

> You may need to keep input from one request until the next request.
>   For example, you may need to re-populate a form after checking it for
>   validation errors.

---

You need to flash the values into the `$_SESSION` by using

```
Input::flash();
```

***You may now access those values by calling the `Input::old()` method.***

If you don't want to put all the `Input`-values in the session, you may filter them by their names:

```
Input::flashOnly('username', 'email');
```

or exclude inputs:

```
Input::flashExcept('password', 'access_key');
```

So in your case, the flashed data from the `$_SESSION` is "sticked" in the form by using

```
Input::old('emailId')
```